# undefined reference to a [function_name] error when compiling fortran under intel compiler

Tags: linux, compilation, fortran

Recently when I try to compile a large Fortran code, I met an error, which is in terms of hypre:

```
/ccs/home/phimar/opt/hypre//lib/libHYPRE.a(par_cr.o): In function `hypre_BoomerAMGCoarsenCR1':

par_cr.c:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `_simd_drand48_pd64x2'

/ccs/home/xialing/opt/hypre//lib/libHYPRE.a(par_cr.o): In function `cr':

par_cr.c:(.text+0xd4e): undefined reference to `_simd_drand48_pd64x2'

/usr/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `/tmp/work/phimar/NGA_2way/bin/arts'

make[1]: *** [arts] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/autofs/na3_home1/phimar/NGA/src'

make: *** [default] Error 2
```

which seems to me that it has something to do with the compiler or the hypre src itself. So I tried to start from a clean version, unzip the hypre 2.6.0b zip file and then load the Intel compiler (with the newest version 13.1.3.192 on Titan). But I ended up with the same error.

Do offer your wisdom if this rings a bell. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/472497

Comment: Note also that the offending references are all in C code.... But Markku has the answer.